# jQuery.AreYouSure Plugin not Working except for Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure): Are-You-Sure v1.9.0. I'm facing a strange problem in vbhtml page. 
The plugin works fine if I change the value of a radio button but not for other elements within the same form.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<form id="MultiSelectedSlidesSettings" name="MultiSelectedSlidesSettings" Class="col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-12 "  >

                <input type="text" value="abc" id="temp"  />
                <input type="radio" name="MaxParticipantResponseType1" id="variable1" value="Variable" checked="checked" />
                <label for="variable1">Variable</label>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default " id="btnSubmitSlide" onclick="xxxx()" value="Save" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function SetMultiSlidesSelectedView() { 
     $("#MultiSelectedSlidesSettings").areYouSure({
                message: 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.'
            });
    }
```

Above code is just for demo purpose, in actual there are other controls as well e.g. checkbox and radio buttons etc.

Prompt message with 'stay/leave' message only appears when I change radio button state. It never appears if I change the text in the input field and/or unchecked/check a checkbox.

Any solution or a workaround would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. Looks like the plugin requires elements within the form element to have name attribute. For example in my example above, input.text was given id but name wasn't set. Once I set the name attribute it worked.

```
<input type="text" value="abc" id="temp" name="temp" />
```